# Error: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Tags: django, runtime-error

I just tried to run hello world in django [1.6.0 alpha] framework on eclipse IDE but it shows runtime error as

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

I had added source code on [bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/nnpkandgmailcom/django_start/src). I had tried some earlier asked question but got no solution. So my question is What cause the problem?

Comment: does it tell you which line the error is on ?

Comment: @karthikr No... I also tried to add breakpoint on different line but it don't reach to either of it.

Comment: where do you get this error ? Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546711/runtimeerror-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-while-calling-a-python-object it might give you some ideas.

Comment: @karthikr I had tried but in my case don't able to figure out which line actually lead to recursion

Comment: oh.. do you have it in pydev? Just try running it on command line then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before starting Django project on eclipse IDE, I was doing Andorid Project on it. I hope the error occurs because of that as the above code builded successfully in friend computer. Later I switch back to ubuntu and solve the error.